# How can I filter ASP.NET Core in Application Insights from our startup app

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights

I would like to filter anything in the following category in our application insights:

- "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics"
- "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware"
- "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker"
- "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure"

I have added the following in our startup app and the only one I could filter is the EF ones but I still see the `Microsoft.AspNetCore` entries:

```
services.AddApplicationInsights(GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"),
                GetEnvironmentVariable("CloudRoleName"),
                MicroserviceName,
                ComponentName);
services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(x => x.AddFilter("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", GetEnvironmentVariable("MinimumLogLevel").GetLogLevel()));
services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(x => x.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore", GetEnvironmentVariable("MinimumLogLevel").GetLogLevel()));
```

This is what I want to filter:

[image]

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
services.AddLogging(options =>
{                
    options.AddFilter("AspNetCoreEnvironment", LogLevel.Trace);
    options.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogLevel.Critical);
    options.AddFilter("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", LogLevel.Critical);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, that the same thing I am using. I even tried yours with no changes and still see logs showing up with the category name of Microsoft.AspNetCore. The only difference is I specify the log level as Information rather than Critical.